# MYSQL Parent -> Child (Comment system with sorting and limiting replies)

Tags: mysql

I have been working on this problem for longer than I care to admit. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I am working on a basic commenting system with replies (limited to one level).

The model I am using is pretty self explanatory.

As you can see,

when `commenterID` and `userID` are equal AND `parentID` is null, it will be a "status update" and should be featured on main page. This is a parent.

**I need to include every replies that have a parent featured on the front page (returning isMain true).**

In my example, ID 1 is the parent status update and ID 3,4 are replies to ID 1.

It will be easier to explain my issue by dumping some data:

```
CREATE TABLE `wallPosts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parentID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `commenterID` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `userID` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `post` text,
  `tags` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;
--------------------------------------------------------

INSERT INTO `wallPosts` VALUES(1, NULL, '1', '1', 'This is a status update', NULL, '2013-07-23 08:34:28');
INSERT INTO `wallPosts` VALUES(3, 1, '1', '1', 'this is a reply to a status update', NULL, '2013-07-23 08:35:39');
INSERT INTO `wallPosts` VALUES(4, 1, '2', '1', 'this is a reply to the status update from another user', NULL, '2013-07-15 11:57:35');
INSERT INTO `wallPosts` VALUES(5, NULL, '1', '2', 'This is a post on a user\\''s wall, should not be displayed on main page', NULL, '2013-07-23 08:37:28');
INSERT INTO `wallPosts` VALUES(6, 5, '1', '2', 'this is a reply to a wall post, should not be displayed on main', NULL, '2013-07-23 08:37:44');
```

This is what I currently have:

### [image: This is what I have]

This is what I want:

### [image: This is what I want]

This is the query I have been using:

```
SELECT

`p`.`id`,
`p`.`parentID`,
`p`.`commenterID`,
`p`.`userID`,
`p`.`post`,

case
when (`p`.`userID` = `p`.`commenterID` and `p`.`parentID` IS NULL)
then 'true'
else 'false'
end as isMain

FROM `wallPosts` `p`

LEFT JOIN `wallPosts` `c` ON `c`.`parentID` = `p`.`parentID` AND `c`.`id` > `p`.`id`

GROUP BY `p`.`id`, `p`.`parentID`

HAVING COUNT(`c`.`id`) < 10
```

This limits the number of replies to the most recent 10.

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: Please provide desired output based on provided sample data

Comment: In your question, you have mentioned, isMain to be true for when parentId is not null and commentId = UserId. But in the above example, only id 3 matches the criteria. Then how do u want in id 4 'ismMain' colulmn should also be true?

Comment: @peterm I want the column isMain to show "true" for id, 3 and 4. In a nutshell, I want to select both parents and replies that should be shown on the front page. Items shown on the front page have their parent `parentID` IS NULL as well as `commenterID` = `parentID`

Comment: @krishnasahoo that's correct. isMain is showing true for the parent post... I need to modify this query to include the replies as well.

Comment: @PLB How can I include replies to parents which have isMain = true?

Comment: ``select `r`.*
from `wallPosts` as `p`
join `wallPosts` as `r`
on (`p`.`id` = `r`.`parentID`)`` ?

Comment: @PLB This only returns replies to posts, whether their parents has isMain true or not

Comment: ``select `r`.* from `wallPosts` as `p` join `wallPosts` as `r` on (`p`.`id` = `r`.`parentID`) where `p`.`isMain` `` ? :s

Comment: @PLB Unknown column 'p.isMain' in 'where clause'... need 'having' instead

Comment: I have added a picture to further describe what I am looking for (which isn't that complicated to begin with quite frankly)

Comment: @Bastien Works perfectly fine for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/28b51/3

Comment: @PLB It does because you added 'isMain' as a field... lol. I'd like to keep the structure as is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following.  refer the sqlfiddle link. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2b731/8

select

```
`p`.`id`,
`p`.`parentID`,
`p`.`commenterID`,
`p`.`userID`,
`p`.`post`,

case
when (`p`.`userID` = `p`.`commenterID` and `p`.`parentID` IS NULL) or parentid in (select id from wallPosts where parentid is null and commenterid=userid)
then 'true'
else 'false'
end as isMain

FROM `wallPosts` `p`  limit 10;
```

as per your requirement I am changing your sql query

```
SELECT

`p`.`id`,
`p`.`parentID`,
`p`.`commenterID`,
`p`.`userID`,
`p`.`post`,

case
when (`p`.`userID` = `p`.`commenterID` and `p`.`parentID` IS NULL) or p.parentid in (select id from wallPosts where parentid is null and commenterid=userid)
then 'true'
else 'false'
end as isMain

FROM `wallPosts` `p`

LEFT JOIN `wallPosts` `c` ON `c`.`parentID` = `p`.`parentID` AND `c`.`id` > `p`.`id`

GROUP BY `p`.`id`, `p`.`parentID`

HAVING COUNT(`c`.`id`) < 10
```

Comment: This does output what I am looking for... however, I still need to be able to limit the number of replies returned.

Comment: Your edit limits every rows. I need to limit the number of replies. For instance, if I have 20 rows of parents, they should all be displayed regardless of limit, but their replies should be limited to a given number.